# Visual Studio 2017 Installer Desktop Shortcut Icon

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to use the Visual Studio Installer for 2017 to package my program. I have added the deployment project to my solution, created a shortcut from the Primary Output in the Application folder, moved that to the User's Desktop folder, and set the icon in properties to the icon in the application folder. In the actual project, under the Properties menu (Project - Properties) I have also set the very same icon as a Resource in the icon box there. I then build the solution.

The problem is, if I run the installer it creates a shortcut on the desktop of the user, but always without the icon I've set. Please can someone help!?

I've tried re-creating the shortcut and re-adding the icon, but all my searches online suggest that the method I'm following should work.

Comment: Did you change/assign the icon to the shortcut itself?

Comment: Yes, in the properties menu of the shortcut

Comment: And also added the actual icon file itself in the `User's Program Files Folder`?

Comment: It's in the "Application Folder" which is the User's Program Files\Company Name\App Name

Comment: It could be a temporary glitch, which happened with me as well, try installing it in another computer, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Unfortunately the same thing is happening for multiple users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue was with the icon itself as once I got a new one it worked. For anyone else who gets this issue, make sure your icon isn't too large, and also just try getting a new one.